# Date Format syntax in where clause in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, where-clause, date-format, sql-date-functions

I have a table with date column in which date is updated in this format - 11/21/2022.

How can I get the results for the last 15 days using this date column in Teradata? Looks like need to change the date format in where clause.

I was using below query which does not work with this format

```
select * 
from table_A 
WHERE date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY) 
               AND CURRENT_DATE
```

This does not give any results.

Comment: The token `date` is a reserved word so if that is intended to be a column name it needs to be quoted as `"date"`. FORMAT only applies to conversions to/from character form. What is the *data type* of the column you are comparing? Is it CHAR(10) or DATE?

Comment: Actually the column name is upload_date, I have just mentioned it as date here. Data type of the column is string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `date` column be *text*, then you must first convert it to a bona fide date using the `TO_DATE()` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_A
WHERE TO_DATE("date", 'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

Note that ideally you should be storing your dates in actual date columns, not as text.  This would avoid the need to call the clunky `TO_DATE()` function.

Comment: Not working. Getting this error - FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 2:6 Arguments length mismatch ''MM/DD/YYYY'': to_date() requires 1 argument, got 2

Comment: Try putting quotes around `date`.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try `td_sysfnlib.TO_DATE("date", 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, maybe there's another function with the same name in `syslib`. Check using `select * from dbc.FunctionsV where functionname = 'to_date';`

Comment: Invalid function 'td_sysfnlib.TO_DATE' and Table not found 'FunctionsV'

Comment: That's not a Teradata error, it's a HiveQL error. Which explains why Teradata syntax and metadata queries also fail.  Maybe try cast("date" as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @AkshayShinde If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be appreciated.